# Oracle 12c database cannot log in as a local user

Tags: oracle, oracle-12c

I met a problem from Oracle 12C Database, when I try to login to the user account with command`conn test/test`, I got prompt of "invalid username/password, logon denied". [image: invalid nsername/password]
when I use `conn test/test@PDBORCL`, I got "Could not resolve the connect identifier specified"[image: Could not resolve identifier]
Can anyone please help me out? I really appreciate!!

Answer (score 2):

Strangely, changing my service name to UPPERCASE has helped!

1. Changed case of service name to UPPERCASE in `tnsnames.ora` for pluggable database ("ORCLPDB" in my case).
2. Follow below commands:

   [image]

   Note: service name in uppercase while connecting ex `SCOTT/TIGER@ORCLPDB`

   Not sure why this has worked for me !!

Comment: It's really strange, but when I create the user and password by using all caps, it works fine. But if I use lower case letters, I get the exact same issue

Answer (score 2):

In the `tnsnames.ora` file, I added an entry for `PDBORCL` in which the `SERVICE_NAME=pdborcl`.  Just changed it to uppercase like  `SERVICE_NAME=PDBORCL` and the problem was solved.

Answer (score 0):

You can also connect directly with below syntax:

```
sqlplus TEST/test@localhost:1521/pdborcl
```

pdborcl is pluggable database name